# Working with DWORDS

Tags: c++, dword

I am trying to make a string of `DWORD` type variables. How can I concatenate them?

```
    char* string;
    DWORD a,b,c;

//abc will get some values here


    strcat(string,a);
    strcat(string,b);
    strcat(string,c);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "concatenate"?

Comment: Convert them to a string and then concatenate them.

Comment: Convert to a string containing the hexadecimal representation for a DWORD?

Comment: `DWORD` is the same as `unsigned int`, so do whatever you would do to convert an `int` to a string.

Comment: try sprintf() instead of strcat()

Comment: Cannot convert from DWORD to const char*

Comment: a) Don´t strcat as first command on a string. First a strcpy. b) Don´t do anything with a thing without memory. c) Use sprintf. d) The tag C++ is wrong here.

Comment: @MarkRansom on my VS2005 DWORD is actually 'typedef unsigned long       DWORD;'

Comment: @marcin_j, and `long` is the same as `int` in VS. For backwards compatibility of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under c++ you can use ostringstream :

```
#include<iostream>
#include <sstream>
int main() {
  std::ostringstream os;
  typedef unsigned long DWORD;
  DWORD dw1 = 1;
  DWORD dw2 = 2;
  DWORD dw3 = 2;
  os << dw1 << "," << dw2 << "," << dw3 << std::endl;
  std::cout << os.str();

  // os.str() returns std::string
  return 0;
}
```

your sample code indicates that you might prefer C solution like:

```
char str[256];
sprintf(str, "%ld %ld %ld", dw1, dw2, dw3);

std::cout << str; // this is of course c++ part :)
```

ps. I have tested this with g++4.8

Comment: If I do a loop, how can I make it so sprintf doesn't overwrite, but adds everything after?

Comment: You can `sprintf` to temporary array, ie.: `char tmp[256]`, and then `strcat(str, tmp)`.